# App.Config in C# Solution

Tags: c#

I have a question concerning the app.config files in a c# solution.  My solution contains 6 projects, among them are 4 Class Library projects, a WCF Application project and a Windows Forms project.  The WCF project and Windows Forms project both contain an app.config file, however in the WCF project it is named "app.config" and the Windows Forms version is "App.config".  I placed a reference for a connection string in the "App.config" version for one of the Class Library projects and I was wondering how the solution knew which config file to use.  I have included both files below.  If any could help me understand this that would be great.  Thanks!!!

## App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="medFactors" connectionString="Data Source=JDH8865-1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MedicalFactors;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <!--<add key="RepositoryType" value="FactorsRepositoryService.WCFServiceRepository,FactorsRepositoryService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
    <add key="RepositoryType" value="FactorsRepositoryCSV.CSVRepository,FactorsRepositoryCSV, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>-->
    <add key="RepositoryType" value="FactorsRepositorySQL.SQLRepository,FactorsRepositorySQL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
    <add key="CSVFileName" value="tbl_Zip-Factors.csv"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:53959/MedFactorsService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonService" contract="WCFMedFactorService.IMedFactorsService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

## app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMedFactorsService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:53959/MedFactorsService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMedFactorsService"
                contract="WCFMedFactorService.IMedFactorsService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMedFactorsService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Usually whichever that is the starting project, its app.config is used for the entire solution.

Comment: Hi oopsdazie and Enigmativity, ok thanks very much for the info, and the edit, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

OK, let me complete the answer.

The App.Config file of a project that is the starting project of a solution, is used as the config file for the solution.